# Compare 2 Dates only by Hour and Minute in Java?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I am trying to compare 2 days (actually 3). In my use case, I have 3 dates that I need to compare. One is StartSleepingTime, StopSleepingTime and Now. My application monitors the user's activity levels and I have a schedueld task that runs every half an hour to check if NOW is between the user's StartSleepingTime and StopSleepingTime in order to make sure that the activity minitoring service is stopped during this interval. Since the user set's the StartSleepingTime and StopSleepingTime in upon first login in when I am running the scheduled tasks both will be in the "past" compared to NOW. Currently I am trying to extract only the hour and minute information from the 3 dates and do a comparison like that:

```
public static boolean compareHrsAndMintsOnly(Date startSH, Date now, Date stopSH) {
    boolean isNowWithinSleepingTime = false;

    Calendar startSHCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    startSHCalendar.setTime(startSH);
    Calendar nowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    nowCalendar.setTime(now);
    Calendar stopSHCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    stopSHCalendar.setTime(stopSH);

    int startSHhour = startSHCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int startSHmin = startSHCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    int nowHour = nowCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int nowMin = nowCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    int stopSHhour = stopSHCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int stopSHmin = stopSHCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if ((startSHhour > nowHour && startSHmin > nowMin) && (nowHour < stopSHhour && nowMin < stopSHmin)) {
        // stop the monitoring service
        isNowWithinSleepingTime = true;
    }else {
       // start the monitoring service

        isNowWithinSleepingTime = false;
    }

    return isNowWithinSleepingTime;

}
```

But this does not work for some reason. In addition, I it feels like there must be a better way to achieve the comparison. Any suggestion please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use joda-time to handle with dates. So i'd have something like:

```
package org.devmaster.sample;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Interval;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public final class Util {

    public static boolean compareHrsAndMintsOnly(Date startSH, Date now, Date stopSH) {
        DateTime start = toDateTime(startSH);
        DateTime end = toDateTime(stopSH);

        Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);

        DateTime instant = toDateTime(now);

        // now is between startSH and stopSH
        return interval.contains(instant);
    }

    private static DateTime toDateTime(Date date) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
        return new DateTime(
                c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

I made a sample if you want to play with: https://github.com/betorcs/jodatime-sample

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will now test if it works. Looks very simple and easy to understand! :)

Comment: I accepted your answer since it is the easiest to implement and it is reliable (library that is proven to be good). Thanks again!

Comment: Just tested it. It dose not work when the startSH and stopSH are in the past :/

Comment: I think i didn't get what you need, sorry, if my example didn't target exactly what you need. My intension was give you a north to you solve your need!

Comment: No worries! In my case the use will set their sleeping hours (e.g. start and stop) just once. They could look like that: StartSH Fri Mar 02 20:00:00 and StopSH Fri Mar 02 08:00:00 (Mar 02 is the date they set their sleeping hours). The problem starts after the Fri Mar 02 is passed (e.g. it is Sat Mar 03 and so on). I am not sure how to compare those past dates with NOW. Thank you for the github link :)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
    Calendar startSHCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    startSHCalendar.setTime(startSH);
    Calendar nowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    nowCalendar.setTime(now);
    Calendar stopSHCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    stopSHCalendar.setTime(stopSH);

    int startSHhour = startSHCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int startSHmin = startSHCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int timeStart = startSHhour*60 + startSHmin;  //this

    int nowHour = nowCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int nowMin = nowCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int timeNow = nowHour*60 + nowMin;  //this

    int stopSHhour = stopSHCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int stopSHmin = stopSHCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int timeStop = stopSHhour*60 + stopSHmin;  //this

    if( timeStart <= timeNow  && timeNow <= timeStop ){
        //between
    }else{
        //not betwwen
    }
```

/!\ Warning, if you are between two days, you must also compare with the day

hope it will help

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It appears to be working during my tests! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
if(nowHour == stopSHhour && nowMin == stopSHmin){ 
    // do something...

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, this check will fail since I am checking every half a hour. For example, a check could occur at 8:15 and the startSleeping time could be 8:00. It has to be > or <